# Explicit template function specializations with overloads: Why would you do it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose the following:

```
template <typename T> void foo (T*);   // #1
template <typename T> void foo (T);    // #2
template <> void foo (int*);           // #3
```

When introducing an explicit specialization of a base template which also has overloads, the specialization is not considered during overload resolution by design. I understand this.

But, given that I could make #3 a non-template overload and it would be then considered for overload resolution, why would I still want to do it as I have done above? Is there a valid use-case for the setup demonstrated above? The only thing I can think of is that if you did not rely on template type deduction, the non-template functions could not be used since they would not accept the `<>` syntax when you call them.

BTW I've only reviewed the rules for C++03. I'm not sure if/how C++11 changes these rules/behaviors.

Comment: mandatory reading: [GotW #49 - Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)- TL;DR Don't do it.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. I'm asking about when you *would* use explicit function specializations in conjunction with overloading. Or, if it shouldn't be done. The linked question's answers do NOT address this question.

Comment: Perhaps there's a non-template based foo in your code that takes an int*. Adding the template specialization means you could be explicit and use foo<int*>(&i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I favor specialization to avoid the principal of least surprise. You want to allow the functions to be called explicitly or non-explicitly to support usage in the widest amount of code possible...and when explicitly instantiated, it should behave the same way as when it was not.

The following template function is an example of how you may want to explicitly select which function you want to call (despite all 3 taking the same argument).

```
template <typename T> void foo (T*){std::cout << 1 << std::endl;}   // #1
template <typename T> void foo (T){std::cout << 2 << std::endl;}    // #2
template <> void foo<int> (int* x){std::cout << 3 << std::endl;}    // #3
//void foo (int*){std::cout << 3 << std::endl;}           // #3

template <typename T>
void bar(void* x) {
   foo<T>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(x));
   foo<T*>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(x));
   foo(reinterpret_cast<T*>(x));
}


int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   bar<int>(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Without the specialization, this outputs 1,2,3 (the explicitly instantiated call is different than the overloaded call), while with the specialization you get 3,2,3 (the explicit instantiation is the same as the implicit call).

Answer (score 1):

`#3` can be used to specialize template functions in one compilation unit without having to update other compilation units.

Let's say we have `z.cpp` which looks like this:

```
template <class T> void foo (T*) { puts("1"); }
template <class T> void foo (T) { puts("2"); }
template <> void foo (int*) { puts("3"); }
void foo(int*) { puts("4"); }

int dummy() {
    foo((int*)NULL);    
    foo<int>((int*)NULL);
    foo(4);    
    foo((long*)NULL);    
}
```

and `y.cpp` which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T> void foo (T*);
template <class T> void foo (T);

int main() {
    foo((int*)NULL);    
    foo<int>((int*)NULL);
    foo(4);    
    foo((long*)NULL);    
}
```

The first lines of main will refer to `#3` and not `#4`. This means that we can specialize `foo` for other types in `z.cpp` without having to change `y.cpp`.

With `#4`, you would have to update `y.cpp` everytime you added a new overload.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that such code violates the one definition rule and as such is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkB - Why? The definitions are only in `z.cpp`.